# Rename a default product type in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to just rename 'Simple Product' into  'Car Parts' in Magento product type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new module. Let's call it `StackExchange_Catalog` with these files.

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Catalog.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Catalog/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <simple>
                        <label>Car Parts</label>
                    </simple>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>
    </global>
</config>
```

Clear the cache and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

check link

http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/change-product-type-in-magento/

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: I think the question is about the selection for new products on creation rather than the actual type. So it will still be a simple product , simply it will say that its car parts.

Comment: ok, Let him decide...what he want.

Comment: The product type will be Simple product, only it will be called as Car parts.